# Como apresentar uma View apenas quando o aplicativo iniciar em Swift 4?

Tags: ios, mac

Bom galera estou fazendo um aplicativo para uma **Entrevista** estou quase terminando porém queria adicionar funcionalidades a mais.

Estou fazendo no xCode utilizando a linguagem swift 4..

O que eu gostaria de saber é, eu tenho uma View chamada **PopUpView** como eu faço para apresenta-la toda vez que o aplicativo iniciar ??

Ou seja quando o aplicativo for executado pelo usuário, toda vez, mostrar essa View..

Comment: seria tipo uma logo ou apresentação do app?
Faça essa view na classe LaunchScreen.storyboard, ela é apresentada ao abrir o aplicativo, depois de um tempo é direcionado para o aplicativo em si

Comment: Entendi, vou ver isso depois.

Answer (score 1):

Opa, blza?

No seu `override func viewDidLoad()` da sua view de entrada(a initial view controller), adicione o seguinte código para chamar a sua PopUpView. Fazendo isso ela irá iniciar a primeira view, e por cima dela a PopUpView.

```
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopUpView") as! PopUpView
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Coloque um botão de voltar na PopUpView e ligue no seu código, para voltar uma view initial, será o seguinte:

```
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Caso deseje apenas colocar uma animacao de entrada no seu app, utilize a LaunchScreen.storyboard, que será a sua spahs.